# Best way to implement page urls without creating pages (dynamic urls?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic

I have been thinking for quite some time now about how I could manage thousands of webpages that change based on a set of data in MySQL.

So in essence, I have thousands of "products" and each is represented by a row in a database table.

What I do currently to page each of these "products" viewable via a url is place a .php file in the url location so that when a user visits `http://www.mydomain.com/some_random_product.php` they are opening one of many .php files that all contain the following:

```
<?php
$thisPageName = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
include '/out/of/root/allProducts.controller.php';
?>
```

So essentially all is hand off the url name to another script that takes the url name then searches the database for a corresponding "product", if it finds the product then it displays a product page with the relevant information and if not it displays an error page stating that the product could not be found.

What I would like to do now, is better that process so that I would not need to create thousands of physical files on the server. Even though this is quite a simple task as I have a script to do it, it just becomes a pain having to run the thing all the time (I have to do it locally as it is a resource hog, then copy all the pages across to the server).

Possibly just one file that all of the urls in that location would load without changing the url as I need it to find the relating info.

I would like to add that the server running the domain is a VPS that I have full access to and I understand that the Apache mod_rewrite module may be of use here but I honestly would not know where to even start in terms of the logic behind implementing that.

If anyone could suggest a better way to do this or anything that may be of relevance then it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should check into the meaning of a "dynamic page".  Creating multiple pages just to display products is not the best solution.  Instead create one page that generates content based on the product id (e.g. `product.php?productId=12`).  I'm sure you could find a tutorial on creating product pages, or something like that as an example.

Comment: @CullyLarson That does make sense but would it really be best to have something like `products.php?src=this_random_product` vs `this_random_product.php` in terms of SEO I think that having a unique url would be better option although I could be wrong?

Comment: Are you asking how to do something like `products/longer-product-name` and have that point to one script (e.g. your `product.php` script), with `longer-product-name` accessible from something like `$_GET['product_name']`?

Comment: @CullyLarson I have currently `products/seo+friendly+url.php`. I would like to have `products/seo+friendly+url.php` but with no physical page, rather just redirect every url accessed within `products/` to load `templates/page_template.php`?

Comment: I see.  I found a couple useful references searching for "htaccess rewrite url get parameters".  This http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/how-to-pass-get-parameters-to-rewritten-url and http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

Comment: @CullyLarson I see, it seems like mod_rewrite is really the only possibly way to accomplish this task efficiently.

Comment: That or just use .htaccess to point your 404 traffic to one PHP script that routes all of your traffic to the appropriate script.

Comment: @CullyLarson that's a good point... The 404's would only relate to the products as these change frequently but I could filter the 404ed url to be sure. Thanks for getting me on the right track! have a look at the link at the bottom of my post before I remove it, what do you think? :)

Comment: Would it be easier to migrate your system to one of the many ecommerce platforms already tried and tested? WooCommerce, Magento etc.? Granted this is not an answer, but they are widely known for a reason... For working well and being easy to implement to excellent SEO...

Comment: @BigChris Where is the fun and learning in that? :) I have paid attention to a lot of them, just trying to implement similar/increased functionality at the moment. (as a note, we are targeting mainly small business however the consumer traffic would be a bonus and hence us wanting pretty URLs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the product ID in the URL and catch it in your PHP script with `$_GET[productId]`.

Then you should query the database to get the row of the product matching that ID and display the data of that product.

To make the URL's pretty for this case **and stay SEO friendly**:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /product/product.php?productId=$1&name=$2
```

```
# URL:
<a href="/product/product.php?productId=123&name=product-one">
    Product one
</a>

<!-- OR (Because of the URL rewriting) -->

<a href="/product/123/product-one">
    Product one
</a>
```

```
# PHP Script
$id = $_GET[productId];

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `product`
WHERE `id` = ?;";

etc...
```

This way you could show thousands of different content on just one simple PHP page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply Houssni. I already have something like this but with SEO friendly urls, more like the second link that was provided by Cully in the comments. I want to avoid having one specific page to deal with thousands, especially with a really not very useful URL like you have mentioned. So essentially instead of searching for the product id, i search its code and description for keywords in a specific order. Cully's Link: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

Comment: This is dangerous advice especially given the user's assumed level of experience.  @IndigoIdentity, be sure to read up on SQL injection and escaping queries before even thinking about using this code. Having said that, this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Jody That's why I've put the question mark over there, parameterized query. And with his level he should be practicing first tho.

Comment: Thanks Houssni and yes you are correct, this would most definitely work however in order to obtain the desired result it would need to be used in conjunction with mod_rewrite. For this reason I think that Mitch has provided the better answer.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity Our answers are the same, except for that I provide a little more information about how to get product results.

Comment: I see now there are some edits :) Please check on the comment for Mitch? It's the same for both of you but you are missing that i am not using GET to retrieve the data, I am using the url its self.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity **URL == GET**

Comment: Houssni, that is not true. You are in mod rewrite pointing to a URL that is in public root, i.e. it is accessible under this name? I am pointing to a file that is out of the public root, i.e. the ONLY thing that is accessible is: `/product/product-one`. Further ie is that i want `/product/product-one` to run a file that is not accessible in the public root.

Comment: what this does is when a user visits, `/product/product-one` they are redirected to `/product/product.php?id=whatever`. I want to keep the url unchanged so it is actually a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have several questions in one here.

Firstly you need to build a dynamic page that retrieves the product information from the database and displays this, based on a unique identifier passed to the page through a querystring/GET parameter.

Example of GET parameter usage in PHP from php.net:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . $_GET["name"] . '!';
?>
```

Assuming the user entered `http://example.com/?name=Hannes`
The above example will output something similar to:
Hello Hannes!

Secondly you want to use mod_rewrite to allow pretty URLs to be accessed, i.e:
`example.com/products/some_random_product` vs `example.com/products.php?id=some_random_product`.

Example Apache mod_rewrite condition to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([^/.]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Based on the questions you've asked I would recommend you do some research into `mod_rewrite`, `$_GET`, and in general the use of PHP to create dynamic web pages.

**Edit on SEO:**

Providing you use mod_rewrite there should be no difference in SEO. The client won't be able to tell that you are really displaying `products.php` rather than `/products/some_random_product`. mod_rewrite is entirely server-side, it is completely different to sending a response to the client telling them the page has moved for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do understand what you are saying and I believe that you do understand what I am getting at too. First part i have done in that I have a script that gets and retrieves the information correctly and then displays either product information or the error based on availability of product information relating to the url values (separated by _). What I always thought i needed was a page that grabs the url then sends it off to the script that processes the request, this works fine... But i have used a single physical page for this aspect each time in the past.

Comment: The second part I guess i am stuck with and yes there are a few unspoken questions within that... I apprecaite the good examples as thats what I needed but I guess another direct question is this. Is it better in terms of SEO to have a unqiue page for each product, or is having one page, `product.php` with multiple extensions generally acceptable? I always thought that having a unique page would be more favorable in the eyes of the crawling and ranking machines.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now, it's actually irrelevant as its not what occurs during run time. I wish i could give you 2 ups :)

Comment: One more question, I do not want to use GET to retrieve data. I want to use the URL name so could I do something like: `RewriteRule ^products/([^/.]+)/?$ /out/of/pub/root/templates/products.php [L]` which loads the file stated in my post (breaks down the url and passes it off to something else)?